# Windows - creating a task for an event from the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, events

I am trying to create a task which is triggered each time an event happens. The event is stopping winrm service, when this happens it should trigger the task to start it up again.
I can do this using the eventviewer interface but I want to do it from the command line - what is the command for this?
Source: Windows Remote Management
Level: Information
Event ID: 212

The task will start powershell.exe and the argument is a ps1 script

Comment: are you sure event id is 212?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$command = "PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned " +
"-WindowStyle Hidden -File 'C:\Script.ps1'"

SCHTASKS /Create /TN "Event Monitor" /TR $command /SC ONEVENT `
/RL Highest /RU $cred.Username /RP $password `
/EC ScriptEvents /MO *[Application/EventID=212]
```